# How to remove the bullet points from this WordPress theme? Thanks

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

This is the css code. I would appreciate if you could let me how to remove the bullet points on side menu. Link: https://www.ability.com.pk/executive-search-selection/

```
}

.rt-menu.element-one ul.menu li{
}

.rt-menu.element-one ul.menu li a{
    display:block;
    padding:5px 25px 9px 25px;
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:17px;
    color:#fff;
    line-height:27px;
    opacity:0.9;
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.rt-menu.element-one ul.menu li a:hover,
.rt-menu.element-one ul.menu li.current-menu-item a{
    opacity:1;
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.12);
}

.rt-menu.element-one ul.menu li ul li a{
    padding-left:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. in your theme's style.css put this code...
2. add custom css in admin panel's custom css 
   here is location...
   [image]

Try this code..
hope you will find your desired result

**here is code....**

```
 .entry-content ul li {
      list-style: none;
    }
```

**if not work yet you need to put !important in it..**

```
.entry-content ul li {
      list-style: none !important;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code..

**css**

```
.side-menu ul li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Not working I did that in the css wpbakery. Normal text box is removing bullet points but the menu is not.

Comment: I checked ttps://www.ability.com.pk/executive-search-selection/ ur link.. its working fine.